# How to update my xts environment with daily stock data?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo, quantmod

I have loaded and saved my environment with more than 300 stocks historical data using `getsymbols` function. Now I am trying to update my historical dataset with the new daily data but it is not working. I tried using `merge()` and `rbind()` but it seems not working with environments. I appreciate your help with this issue !

Here is my code:

```
load.packages('quantmod')        
tickers = spl('A,AA,AAL,AAP,AAPL,ABT,ACN,ADBE,ADI,ADM,ADP,ADS,AEE,AEP')
getSymbols(tickers, src = 'yahoo', from = '2010-01-01' , env = data, auto.assign = TRUE)
save(data, file="myTickersData.rda")
```

Now, I am trying to append it with today's data without re-running it all again from 2010 as it will take a lot of time.

```
data.today = new.env()
getSymbols(tickers, src = 'yahoo', from = '2015-10-14' , env = data.today, auto.assign = T)
updated.data = merge(data,data.today)
```

I am getting this error:

> `Error in as.data.frame.default(x) :`
>   `cannot coerce class ""environment"" to a data.frame`

Comment: Where do the `load.packages` and `spl` functions come from?

Comment: Sorry Joshua I forgot to mention that ! these functions are from the SIT (systematic Investment toolbox)   
con = gzcon(url('http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'))
source(con)
close(con)
load.packages('quantmod')
#tickers = dow.jones.components()
tickers = spl('SPY,SHY,AAPL,ADBE,AMZN,DHI,DIS')

Comment: Appending the data is a really bad idea! Historical stock data is changing after every dividend, split or cash distribution. So after appending your data for a few months it’s practically useless. You really should download it daily or if you have the knowledge and you are prepared to put in the time and effort you can maintain a database with the raw data and do all the necessary work yourself. ( keeping corporate actions adjustment factors, cash dividends adjustment factors, mapping of changed symbols, e.g. mergers, spin-offs etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that should do most of what you need. Some important things it doesn't do:

1. It doesn't check to ensure that you don't `rbind` a duplicate date
   to the historical data.
2. It doesn't back-adjust all historical data if there's a split,
   dividend, etc between updates.

To solve the second issue, you would need to re-pull all the data for the given symbol.

```
updateData <- function(oldData, newData) {
  # ensure both arguments are environments
  stopifnot(is.environment(oldData) || is.environment(newData))
  # track symbols that aren't in the new environment
  unmatchedSym <- NULL
  # loop over all symbols in the historical data environment
  for (sym in ls(oldData)) {
    # get a copy of the symbol data
    oldSym <- get(sym, oldData)
    # try to get the new data
    newSym <- try(get(sym, newData))
    if (inherits(newSym, "try-error")) {
      unmatchedSym <- c(unmatchedSym, sym)
      next
    } else {
      # rbind old/new data
      # might want to check to ensure you're not adding a dupicate row
      combined <- rbind(oldSym, newSym)
      # update historical data environment
      assign(sym, combined, oldData)
    }
  }
  # return unmatched symbols (invisibly)
  invisible(unmatchedSym)
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
library(quantmod)
oldData <- new.env()
getSymbols("A;AA;AAL", env=oldData, to="2015-09-30")

newData <- new.env()
getSymbols("A;AA;AAL", env=newData, from="2015-10-01")

updateData(oldData, newData)
eapply(oldData, tail)
# $AA
#            AA.Open AA.High AA.Low AA.Close AA.Volume AA.Adjusted
# 2015-10-08   10.85   11.11  10.63    11.01  34172000       11.01
# 2015-10-09   10.67   10.92  10.25    10.26  78627900       10.26
# 2015-10-12   10.28   10.29   9.97    10.08  31371900       10.08
# 2015-10-13    9.96   10.22   9.86    10.03  36220300       10.03
# 2015-10-14   10.09   10.11   9.91     9.95  42245400        9.95
# 2015-10-15    9.93   10.00   9.63     9.70  49779200        9.70
#
# $A
#           A.Open A.High A.Low A.Close A.Volume A.Adjusted
# 2015-10-08  35.39  36.07 35.34   36.01  2597900      36.01
# 2015-10-09  35.94  36.34 35.88   36.23  3230000      36.23
# 2015-10-12  36.08  36.18 35.86   35.99  1258300      35.99
# 2015-10-13  35.76  36.24 35.53   35.63  2379300      35.63
# 2015-10-14  35.64  35.77 34.97   35.05  1644300      35.05
# 2015-10-15  35.12  35.68 34.79   35.58  1427300      35.58
#
# $AAL
#           AAL.Open AAL.High AAL.Low AAL.Close AAL.Volume AAL.Adjusted
# 2015-10-08    39.21    40.03   38.70     39.74    8303200        39.74
# 2015-10-09    40.27    42.49   40.25     42.42   16797000        42.42
# 2015-10-12    42.59    43.88   42.55     43.84   11437200        43.84
# 2015-10-13    42.70    43.97   42.52     43.41   13212600        43.41
# 2015-10-14    44.00    44.50   43.23     43.80   11121500        43.80
# 2015-10-15    44.10    44.48   43.50     44.46    8179500        44.46
```